# Netbeans ignoring files

Tags: c++, git, netbeans

In Netbeans when I create a new C++ project from existing sources only the Makefile appears to be under Git version control.  The other files (.h, .cpp) all appear to be ignored (grayed out) when viewing from the Projects or Files windows in Netbeans.

How do I make these files tracked?

I have already tried the right-click unignore option.
I do not have a .gitignore file at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore files in git in other ways than using the `.gitignore`.

In project folder check the file `.git/info/exclude` - you can exclude files which yu don't want to keep in .gitignore (which is usually shared with other coders)

You can also ignore files on a global level. Check the settings of Netbeans - it might have a global ignore list used by git.

Comment: Thank you -- I ended up converting to a Netbeans project and then all of the files were now recognized by Git in Netbeans.  They were always recognized by Git outside of the IDE.